# How to read html tags from a Model property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I am working on a MVC page which has few hyperlinks which when clicked will open a new tab with some content which is part of a Model property

The issue I am facing is that the Model property which holds the value already has Html tags, which is throwing an error **Unexpected Token &**

```
function popUp() {

        var newWindow = window.open();

        newWindow.document.open();
        newWindow.document.write('@Model.SomeProperty');
        newWindow.document.close();

    }
```

How can I achieve this?

This is the content of Model property 
**Widerrufsrecht:**\r\n
\r\n
Sie können Ihre Vertragserklärungen, sofern diese nicht im Handel abgegeben wurden, innerhalb von 14 Tagen ohne Angabe von Gründen in Textform (z. B. Brief, Fax, E-Mail) widerrufen.

Comment: Considering this is a js function, you most likely need to wrap `@Model.SomeProperty` with quotes (single or double) like so `'@Model.SomeProperty'`, without the quotes javascript is seeing it as an object (with variables, etc) and not as a string.

Comment: I am getting an error with '' as well, and the error says popUp is not a function

Comment: Can you post the changes you made?

Comment: Is this within a js file or cshtml file?

Comment: the JS snippet is within the cshtml file

Comment: Great, and is Model.SomeProperty highlighted?  Also what is the contents of SomeProperty?

Comment: Yes it is highlighted

Comment: Hmm, I've update my answer to use the Raw function, have a look at that

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to look like this

```
function popUp() {
    var newWindow = window.open();
    var html = jQuery("#hiddenremark").value;

    newWindow.document.open();
    newWindow.document.write('@(Model.SomeProperty)');
    //or
    newWindow.document.write('@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.SomeProperty))')
    newWindow.document.close();
}
```

As you want to pass in a string value and not an object.

**Note**:
This will only work in a **cshtml** file, not in a **js** file.

Comment: Still doesn't work, when page loads i am getting , Unexpected token ILLEGAL error, and when i click on the hyperlink i am getting popup is not defined

Comment: @CSharped I added the `Html.Encode`, if that doesn't work, then I don't know :( sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code comes from view. You should escape quotes `'` from `Model.SomeProperty`, try:

```
newWindow.document.write('@Model.SomeProperty.Replce("'", "\'"');
```

**Hint**: Look at page source in browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am using to send HTML code in a  Model Property (In C#).

`[AllowHtml]
public string MailBody { get; set;}`